# changes needed to install Webmin on a server running Gentoo

Tags: gentoo, webmin

I'm trying to setup a www.kimsufi.com server running Gentoo and to install Webmin to administrate it.

I used the command : emerge webmin

and it returned :

```
    !!! Found 2 make.conf files, using both '/etc/make.conf' and '/etc/portage/make.conf'
    !!! SYNC setting found in make.conf.
    This setting is Deprecated and no longer used.  Please ensure your 'sync-type' and 'sync-uri' are set correctly in /etc/portage/repos.conf/gentoo.conf

    * IMPORTANT: 11 news items need reading for repository 'gentoo'.
    * Use eselect news read to view new items.


    * IMPORTANT: 2 config files in '/etc/portage' need updating.
    * See the CONFIGURATION FILES section of the emerge
 * man page to learn how to update config files.
Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild  N     ] sys-apps/tcp-wrappers-7.6.22-r1  USE="ipv6 -netgroups -static-libs" ABI_X86="(64) -32 (-x32)" 
[ebuild  N     ] media-fonts/liberation-fonts-2.00.1-r1  USE="-X -fontforge" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/XML-NamespaceSupport-1.110.0-r1 
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-Digest-MD5-2.530.0-r2 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/IO-Tty-1.120.0 
[ebuild  N     ] media-libs/libpng-1.6.16  USE="-apng (-neon) -static-libs" ABI_X86="(64) -32 (-x32)" 
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-Digest-SHA-5.880.0 
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-MIME-Base64-3.140.0-r1 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/XML-Generator-1.40.0-r1 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Net-SSLeay-1.650.0 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Sys-Hostname-Long-1.400.0-r1 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Crypt-OpenSSL-Random-0.40.0-r1 
[ebuild  N    ~] dev-perl/Getopt-GUI-Long-0.930.0-r1 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/XML-SAX-Base-1.80.0-r1 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Net-IP-1.260.0-r1 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Socket6-0.250.0 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/TimeDate-2.300.0 
[ebuild  N     ] perl-core/libnet-1.270.0  USE="-sasl" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-lang/nasm-2.11.06  USE="-doc" 
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/ttf-fonts-1 
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-Storable-2.490.100-r1 
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-Time-Local-1.230.0-r1 
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-Time-HiRes-1.972.600-r1 
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-Sys-Syslog-0.330.0-r1 
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-Socket-2.13.0 
[ebuild  N     ] media-libs/freetype-2.5.5  USE="adobe-cff bindist bzip2 -X -auto-hinter -debug -doc -fontforge -harfbuzz -infinality -png -static-libs -utils" ABI_X86="(64) -32 (-x32)" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/XML-SAX-0.990.0-r1 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Authen-PAM-0.160.0-r1 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/MD5-2.30.0-r1 
[ebuild  N    ~] dev-perl/Authen-Libwrap-0.220.0-r1  USE="{-test}" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/IPC-Run-0.920.0-r1  USE="{-test}" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Digest-HMAC-1.30.0-r1 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/IO-Socket-INET6-2.720.0 
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-libnet-1.270.0 
[ebuild  N     ] media-libs/libjpeg-turbo-1.3.1  USE="-java -static-libs" ABI_X86="(64) -32 (-x32)" 
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/jpeg-0-r2  USE="-static-libs" ABI_X86="(64) -32 (-x32)" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/MailTools-2.120.0-r1 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/Net-DNS-0.740.0  USE="ipv6 {-test}" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/XML-LibXML-2.1.400-r1  USE="{-test}" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/XML-Simple-2.200.0-r1 
[ebuild  N     ] media-libs/fontconfig-2.11.1-r2  USE="-doc -static-libs" ABI_X86="(64) -32 (-x32)" 
[ebuild  N     ] app-eselect/eselect-fontconfig-1.1 
[ebuild  N     ] media-libs/gd-2.0.35-r4  USE="fontconfig jpeg png truetype zlib -static-libs -xpm" ABI_X86="(64) -32 (-x32)" 
[ebuild  N     ] media-gfx/graphviz-2.26.3-r4  USE="nls -cairo -doc -examples -gtk -java -lasi -perl -python -ruby -static-libs -tcl" 
[ebuild  N     ] dev-perl/GraphViz-2.140.0  USE="{-test}" 
[ebuild  N    ~] net-dns/dnssec-tools-2.1  USE="-static-libs" 
[ebuild  N    ~] app-admin/webmin-1.730  USE="ssl -ldap -minimal -mysql -postgres" 

The following keyword changes are necessary to proceed:
 (see "package.accept_keywords" in the portage(5) man page for more details)
# required by app-admin/webmin-1.730::gentoo
# required by webmin (argument)
=net-dns/dnssec-tools-2.1 ~amd64
# required by webmin (argument)
=app-admin/webmin-1.730 ~amd64
# required by app-admin/webmin-1.730::gentoo
# required by webmin (argument)
=dev-perl/Authen-Libwrap-0.220.0-r1 ~amd64
# required by net-dns/dnssec-tools-2.1::gentoo
# required by app-admin/webmin-1.730::gentoo
# required by webmin (argument)
=dev-perl/Getopt-GUI-Long-0.930.0-r1 ~amd64

The following USE changes are necessary to proceed:
 (see "package.use" in the portage(5) man page for more details)
# required by media-gfx/graphviz-2.26.3-r4::gentoo
# required by dev-perl/GraphViz-2.140.0::gentoo
# required by net-dns/dnssec-tools-2.1::gentoo
# required by app-admin/webmin-1.730::gentoo
# required by webmin (argument)
>=media-libs/gd-2.0.35-r4 truetype jpeg png fontconfig

Use --autounmask-write to write changes to config files (honoring
CONFIG_PROTECT). Carefully examine the list of proposed changes,
paying special attention to mask or keyword changes that may expose
experimental or unstable packages.
```

When I try to access webmin on the server-ip.10000 I can't access Webmin ...

Could anyone please help me ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package was not installed and your use flags/keywords need to be configured for it. `--autounmask-write` will stage the use flag changes and `dispatch-config` will apply them.

To fix this:

```
emerge --autounmask-write webmin
```

Then run

```
dispatch-conf
```

carefully review the changes and press the command for use-new. Once `dispatch-conf` is finished run `emerge webmin` again and it should work.

[Here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Dispatch-conf) is more info about `dispatch-conf`.